# How to construct the date from year and day of the year

Tags: r

Given the following data.

```
year <- rep(2016,3)
yday <- c(40, 100, 260)
date <- c('2016-02-09','2016-04-09','2016-09-16')

df <- data.frame(year=year, yday=yday, date=date)
```

I would like to construct the date based on the year and yday columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `?strptime` - it lists all the options for formatting dates:

```
> as.Date(paste(yday,year), format="%j %Y")
#[1] "2016-02-09" "2016-04-09" "2016-09-16"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lubridate you could do

```
date <- as.POSIXct(paste0(year,"-01-01"))
yday(date) <- yday

date
# [1] "2016-02-09 CET"  "2016-04-09 CEST" "2016-09-16 CEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.Date` to generate the first date of the `year` and then add the `yday` to it

```
as.Date(paste0(df$year, "-01-01")) + df$yday - 1

#[1] "2016-02-09" "2016-04-09" "2016-09-16"
```